# Latex on Fedora 24

Tags: format-files

I had to install Fedora 24 (beta as today) because my laptop was too new and needed latest version of Kernel.

Everything quite good, but the issue now is that I want to compile latex and seems that something is not ready yet. I have done

```
dnf install texlive-scheme-basic
```

and then try to compile any latex file. But this is what happens:

```
$ latex test.tex  
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.16 (TeX
Live 2016/dev) (preloaded format=latex)  restricted \write18 enabled.

kpathsea: Running mktexfmt latex.fmt Errno architecture
(x86_64-linux-thread-multi-4.3.5-300.fc23.x86_64) does not match
executable architecture
(x86_64-linux-thread-multi-4.4.6-301.fc23.x86_64) at
/usr/lib64/perl5/Errno.pm line 11. Compilation failed in require at
/usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl/File/Temp.pm line 17. BEGIN
failed--compilation aborted at
/usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl/File/Temp.pm line 17. Compilation failed
in require at /usr/share/texlive/tlpkg/TeXLive/TLUtils.pm line 206.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at
/usr/share/texlive/tlpkg/TeXLive/TLUtils.pm line 206. Compilation
failed in require at /usr/bin/mktexfmt line 48. BEGIN
failed--compilation aborted at /usr/bin/mktexfmt line 48. I can't find
the format file `latex.fmt'!
```

Then, I

```
$ locate latex.fmt

/home/me/.texlive2007/texmf-var/web2c/pdftex/latex.fmt
/home/me/.texlive2007/texmf-var/web2c/pdftex/pdflatex.fmt
[sequi@sequi6 latex]$ cp
/home/me/.texlive2007/texmf-var/web2c/pdftex/latex.fmt
```

And now happens this:

```
$ latex test.tex  
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.16 (TeX
Live 2016/dev) (preloaded format=latex)  restricted \write18 enabled.
---! latex.fmt doesn't match pdftex.pool (Fatal format file error; I'm stymied)
```

Can anyone help me in what to do to correctly compile latex files in Fedora 24?

Comment: https://www.tug.org/texlive/ is always a better option. I never you the distribution managed version

Comment: Welcome! Install vanilla TeX Live. It is, as mentioned already, a better option anyway. You can install 2015 now and 2016 when the stable version is released. That said, it does depend what is screwing up things on Fedora. As it is beta... if something like perl is screwy, then TeX Live will be problematic, too. Search `vanilla` on this site and look for the first very popular question. Just translate for Fedora as the question is for Debian-based distros. (But it works fine on Fedora, Arch etc.)

Comment: How did you end up with TL2016 binaries with what seems to be a TL2007 installation?

Comment: `rm -fr /home/me/.texlive2007`

Comment: Answer to cfr: I've done as you say and I got the same error message when I type "./install-tl " (see below).  This would mean a problem with perl looks like, no?  I've tried to updated, but is up to date.  Thanks, ezequiel.

=========
[root@sequi6 install-tl-20160405]# ./install-tl 
Errno architecture (x86_64-linux-thread-multi-4.3.5-300.fc23.x86_64) does not match executable architecture (x86_64-linux-thread-multi-4.4.6-301.fc23.x86_64) at /usr/lib64/perl5/Errno.pm line 11.
Compilation failed in require at /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl/File/Temp.pm line 17.
.... (continues the same)

Comment: to Axel Sommerfeldt: I've tried that and still the same thing. Thanks!

Comment: Are you running a 64 bit install of Fedora? Because from your error messages it looks like it is choking on a 64 bit install.

Comment: I Solved it:

"dnf update perl-Errno.x86_64"

Thanks all!  (I have ASKED the question, and this SOLVES it.  I have placed the solution here, but a moderator has deleted arguing that "This does not provide an answer".  Haha.., I had the problem and I solved it, so I would guess that I do know that this DOES provide an answer.  Cheers.)

Comment: Well, it doesn't solve the problem asked about in the question. It solves a problem discussed in the comments which was encountered trying to implement a suggested solution to the original problem.

Comment: If you are doing partial updates of beta Fedora and mixing pre-release upstream binaries with stuff from 2007, then, really, you must expect stuff to break. I guess Fedora supports partial updates in some cases, but you probably need to take precautions in that case.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem. The following fixed it for me:

```
sudo texconfig rehash
```